# Is it possible to use async/await in webmethod asmx service

Tags: asynchronous, asmx, webmethod, async-await

I am trying to figured it out, but have no success for now. Is it possible to use async/await in webmethod asmx service ? What I found till now is that async/await can be used only in WCF service method (rest or whatever).

Comment: WCF was released in 2006 as a recommended replacement for asmx. Asmx was officially declared a "legacy technology" in 2009. If you're planning to change the code anyway to make it `async`, why not change it to a newer platform?

Comment: In general, you should not expect ASMX to keep up with modern technology. It is legacy software, kept around for backwards compatibility. Consider the following question: why should Microsoft has spent money testing `async`/`await` on ASMX services?

Comment: Stephen, John, thank you for your comments. I guess I should go in direction to migrate my existing asmx service to wcf.

Comment: John, you marked the question as duplicated, but the question you marked  as source is asked more than one year after this question.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bad idea. You're basically trying to use a modern language feature with a legacy technology - when .asmx was introduced the notion of asynchronous services wasn't really established.

An answer may lie here though:

[Is there some way to handle async/await behind an ASMX service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622372/is-there-some-way-to-handle-async-await-behind-an-asmx-service)

I'd say stick to WCF or WebAPI.