Calling ASMX task based method with object parameter results in Unknown web method error
I have an async ASMX web method which works as expected when passing a simple string (I followed the excellent information provided by Stephen Cleary on this question Calling Task-based methods from ASMX
If I post a json object via an XmlHttpRequest to a sync method, this works OK (the object's underlying type is Dictionary<string,object> but if I try to pass the same js object to the async version, I get the Unknown web method error, even though the WSDL indicates that the method MyDownload exists.
What am I doing wrong/missing?
Javascript:
        let jobUrl = '@Helpers.GetUrl(Request, "SiteService.asmx/MyDownload", false)'; //Fails
        //let jobUrl = '@Helpers.GetUrl(Request, "SiteService.asmx/MyTest", false)'; // Succeeds
        let tmp = {};
        tmp.myDownloadViewModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
        ajaxQuery(jobUrl, 'POST', 'json', tmp, function (result) {
        ...
        });

SiteService.asmx.cs:
using ...

namespace MyCompany.Namespace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for SiteService1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://mycompany.co.uk/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [ScriptService]
    public class SiteService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string MyTest(object myDownloadViewModel)
        {
            var x = 1;

            return "ok";
        }

        // Async webmethod info from Stephen Cleary https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078621/calling-task-based-methods-from-asmx
        private async Task<string> FooAsync(string patientId)
        {
            ....
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public IAsyncResult BeginMyDownload(object myDownloadViewModel, AsyncCallback cb, object state)
        {
...
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string EndMyDownload(IAsyncResult res)
        {
            return ((Task<string>)res).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }
}

