# How to call an async function inside web-service method in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

## How to call an async function inside web service method in c# ##

Here is my sample code and I want to call `btndisplayword_Click` from `DisplayNextWord` and `DisplayNextWord` is async so that won't work

```
[WebMethod]
    public static void DisplayNextWord(int id)
    {

        ///How to call below async function inside webservice Here

    }


protected async void btndisplayword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
```

Comment: The same way you would call it from any syncronous method. Have you checked if is already answered? First search gives me a duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there some way to handle async/await behind an ASMX service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622372/is-there-some-way-to-handle-async-await-behind-an-asmx-service)

Comment: add some words to make it clear

Comment: @Princy are you limited to ASMX or can go to WCF or WebAPI? ASMX doesn't supports TPL by design, and the hacks required may lead to clumsy code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code works...... ####

```
 [WebMethod]
            public static void DisplayWord(int id)
            {

                SpellingBee_spellbyte Sg = new SpellingBee_spellbyte();//pageclassname
                Task.Run(async () => await Sg.getstartWord(id));


            }


  protected async Task getstartWord(int tagId)
        {
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call the non-static function into a static function. Either make your click event static or DisplayNextWord method non-static.

```
    public void DisplayNextWord(int id)
    {
        btndisplayword_Click(null, null);
    }

    protected async void btndisplayword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
```

Comment: A webmethod when its a part of ASPX code behind will need to be a static method. However if its part of a webservice method, it can be an instance one. Here, its a part of aspx (has a button click handler) and the handler itself need to be instance one to allow the event to bind